# failed to parse manifest - no targets specified

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and attempting to build a test project with Cargo. My `Cargo.toml` looks like:

```
[package]
name = "rust-play"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [ "Bradley Wogsland <omitted>" ]
```

(but the actual TOML file doesn't omit my email). When I `cargo build` I am getting the following error:

> error: failed to parse manifest at `/Users/wogsland/Projects/rust-play/Cargo.toml`
>
> Caused by:
>     no targets specified in the manifest
>     either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present

My `main` function is in a `src/test.rs` file. Do I need to specify that in the TOML file? If so, how? I tried adding

```
target = "src/test.rs"
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As the error says:

> either `src/lib.rs`, `src/main.rs`, a `[lib]` section, or `[[bin]]` section must be present

So the direct answer is to [add a `[[bin]]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#configuring-a-target):

```
[[bin]]
name = "test"
path = "src/test.rs"
```

However, it's far more usual to just place the file in the expected location: `src/main.rs`. You could also place it in `src/bin/test.rs` if you plan on having multiple binaries.

If it's actually for testing your code, then unit tests go in the same file as the code they are testing and integration tests go in `tests/foo.rs`.

Comment: I had the problem while installing IntelliJ IDEA and it being confused on the matter, but this solved the intellij idea error.

Answer (score 17):

*Alternative issue and solution:* You can also be faced with this error if you have copied `Cargo.toml` file to a **parent folder** of the crate.

Comment: Why is that? Is this a bug?

Comment: No, not a bug, `cargo` tries to find the root of the project. It works this way to allow you to run `cargo` command in subcrate's folder of a workspace.

Answer (score 3):

In my case and probably in your case as well, the rs file was not named `main.rs` while Cargo assumes that `src/main.rs` is the crate root of a binary crate. So, the rule is that If project is an executable, name the main source file `src/main.rs`. If it is a library, name the main source file `src/lib.rs`.

Additionally, Cargo will also treat any files located in `src/bin/*.rs` as executables like mentioned in the previous answer.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more to highlight what is different about this answer as opposed to the other answer? The other answer already says "place the file in the expected location: `src/main.rs`"

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for asking. In my answer, I tried to explicitly highlight the 'renaming' of file to `main.rs` if someone is using any other name but still has it in location: `srs`. Something which was not clearly mentioned in your answer that it has to be `main.rs` file and no other name. Also, felt imp to mention about library. 

Can I request to take back the negative vote? :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 after having inadvertently copied `Cargo.toml` to my home folder. Even though my working directory had a properly defined `Cargo.toml`, the copy in `$HOME` was taking precedence and causing builds to fail.

Answer (score 1):

As a summary:

If you use `cargo new xxx --bin`, you will find the file in the `src` directory is named `main.rs`. And when you check the file `Cargo.toml`. It is the same as you written. So the first way is to change the file in src to `main.rs`

As the cargo report, we can use the `[[bin]]` to set the file.  @Shepmaster has solved it.

Both two ways can work.

Comment: Can you explain what new information this answer provides compared to the existing answer?

Comment: All right, I just found that your answer has explained both of two ways.@Shepmaster, Actually, I am new to rust, and I encountered the same problem, so I posted that answer when i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and it was because the parent directory also contained a Cargo.toml file and it was prioritising that over the one in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

I did stumble over this problem today. But this time it was caused by an invalid cargo.toml somewhere in the parent directory hierarchy.

Even if at the root mount there is an invalid /cargo.toml file , all builds at that server will fail.

The workaround, proposed in this forum topic https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-is-the-correlation-between-two-cargo-toml-in-the-file-hierarchy/101933, was to turn the cargo.toml file into a standalone workspace, by adding a `[workspace]` section in the cargo.toml file.